# SDL exit fullscreen

Tags: c++, sdl, fullscreen, exit

When I exit my fullscreen SDL application, my computer resolution changes to 640x480. 
My application resolution is 1024x768. How can I switch back the resolution to its original resolution after exiting the application?

I use SDL 1.2 and Ubuntu 10.04

Comment: Sounds like something that would happen if you forgot to call `SDL_Quit()` at the end of your app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That sounds like a X driver problem or window manager problem. Can you try it on different distro or different ubuntu version?

Unless your program crash, you should call `SDL_Quit()`, or  `SDL_QuitSubSystem(SDL_INIT_VIDEO)`, or just exit the full screen. That should restore original settings.

Answer (score 1):

Try forcing a switch back to windowed mode first via `SDL_SetVideoMode(...)`